# Login to Yahoo Mail programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, automation, httpwebrequest, yahoo

I'm doing this for learning this specific approach, so please do not suggest alternates like Yahoo API or Yahoo SMTP etc.

I'm trying to login to my yahoo account and read my inbox by emulating browser actions using `HttpWebRequest` and other companion classes. Using Chrome Developer tools, I can see all the different actions, forms, data etc. that is passed between the browser and the server. The problem is that while the browser successfully lands in the inbox, my WebRequest is always redirected back to the "Sign In" page when I post my form.

Here are a few extra things I have already done:

1. I have fetched `Challenge` and `U` parameters that are required for logging in.
2. I'm already doing `MD5(MD5(pwd) + Challenge)` that Google tells is required.

If anyone has done this before, plz guide what am I missing here?

Comment: Are you preserving cookies.

Comment: Not 100% sure. I'm using a wrapper class that does have a property named `HandleCookies`, which I'm setting to `true`.

Comment: Use Fiddler to compare your requests to a real browser.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking for this, I was finally able to solve it myself. Didn't need Fiddler, Chrome Developer Tools do good enough of a job.

1. Do not listen to guys who ask you to MD5 the password. Send plain password.
2. COOKIES, as SLaks mentioned. Preserve cookies.

That completes my experiment. Thanks for your input guys.